# Lucene BooleanQuery with multiple FuzzyQuery is too slow

Tags: java, lucene

A [Document](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html) is an employee data of a company with multiple fields name like: `empName, empId, departmentId etc`.

Using custom analyzer have indexed around 4 million data.

Search query is having a `list` `of` `employees'` `name`, and know that all employees in list belong to same department. There are multiple departments in company.

So I want to do `fuzzy search` for all employees' names for under given `department id`.

For this I am using boolean query which looks like:

```
Query termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("departmentId","1234"));
BooleanQuery.Builder bld = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
for(String str:employeeNameList) {
    bld.add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("name",str)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
 }       
BooleanQuery bq = bld.build();
BooleanQuery finalBooleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
                .add(termQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
                .add(bq, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST).build();
```

Now passing `finalBooleanQuery` inside  `search` method of `IndexSearcher`  and getting results.

Problem is its taking **too much time**, when size of employeeNameList `more than 50` it takes around `500 ms` for search.

How can I reduce time from `500 ms` to  `50 ms` ?

There is any other solution for this problem ?

Comment: why you're adding boolean clause for every employee?

Comment: @Mysterion is there any other way doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the other constructors for `FuzzyQuery`, you'll see some easy ways to improve performance. Each additional argument is there for you to reduce the amount of work the FuzzyQuery is going to do, and so improve performance.

First, and most important:

- Prefix length: I *strongly* recommend setting this to a non-zero value. This is how many characters at the beginning of the term will *not* be subject to fuzzy matching. So, if searching for "abc" with a prefix of 1, "abb" and "acc" would be matched, but not "bbc". This allows lucene to work with the index when attempting to find matching terms, instead of having to scan the whole term dictionary. It's likely you will see the largest performance improvement here. Many seem to find *2* to be a good balance point between performance and meeting search demands.

The rest of the available arguments can also help:

- maxEdits - 2 is the default, and the maximum. Setting this to 1 will match less, and as such, work faster.
- maxExpansions - Under the hood, this query finds terms that match the fuzzy parameters, then performs a search for those terms. If you are searching for short terms, especially, this list of matching terms could turn out to be very long. Setting maxExpansions will prevent these extremely long lists of matches from occurring. Default is 50.
- transpositions - Whether swapping two characters is an allowed edit. Default is true. Basically, the difference between Levenshtein and Damerau-Levenshtein. false is less work and less matches, so will perform better. Don't know if the difference will be that big though.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I already went through other constructors with additional arguments. But having some limitations with setting arguments.
**Prefix length**: During indexing I am using **DoubleMetaphoneFilter**, So fixing prefix length can change results.

**maxEdits**:  Employee name can have spelling mistakes more than 1, can't change maxEdits to 1.

**maxExpansions**: There are only few cases where this can help.

**transpositions**: This also can help, but will not get expected fuzzy results without swapping characters.